# JAR file running from another directory?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I created a JAR file with my Java program. This piece of code will open a few files inside a dir "Test", which is in the same dir as the JAR file. Like this:

```
/
 -- program.jar
 -- /Test
     -- *
```

If I run via terminal with: java -jar program.jar, it runs perfectly. But if I run graphically (right clicking on the jar file and Open with OpenJDK...), it doesn't work properly. Just like if I ran from another directory.

Is it possible that when I run the JAR file graphically it's running from another directory?

By the way, I'm running on Ubuntu.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/234777 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=535277 bug reports.  Seems like nothing can be done right now.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine it was a bug on nautilus. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot assume _anything_ about the current working directory when running a Java program.  You can however ask the JVM about e.g. where a given class was loaded from, and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will get another current working directory... There would be two solutions:

**1)** Find the cwd by doing this hack:

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String... args) { 

            ClassLoader cl = Test.class.getClassLoader();
            String f = cl.getResource("").getFile();

            File cwd = new File(f);

            if (cwd.toString().endsWith("!"))
                cwd = cwd.getParentFile();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cwd);
        }
    }
```

**2)** If the files under `Test` are static (does not change to often) the solution would be to package them inside the jar.

Comment: Isn't there any solution for this? Because the Test dir isn't static.

Comment: Note that the hack shown assumes quite a bit and may not work for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but below is a link to similar JAR question.

[Running jar file with source files in another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512275/running-jar-file-with-source-files-in-another-directory)

Comment: That doesn't look like a solution.

Comment: I've seen this post before, but it really doesn't help. :(